# Ansible ping works but the ansible-playbook receives "Failed to connect to the host via ssh"

Tags: ansible

I have this issue when I ping all inventory it works:

```
ansible all -m ping --user ubuntu  --private-key /path/to_key
```

it pings them succesfully

```
10.0.1.50 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
10.0.1.40 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
10.0.1.100 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
10.0.1.200 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

but if I try to run a playbook

```
ansible-playbook system_info.yml  --user ubuntu  --private-key /path/to_key
```

I get  "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Connection closed by port 22", "unreachable": true}

```
fatal: [10.0.1.200]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Connection closed by 10.0.1.200 port 22", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [10.0.1.40]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Connection closed by 10.0.1.40 port 22", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [10.0.1.50]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Connection closed by 10.0.1.50 port 22", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [10.0.1.100]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Connection closed by 10.0.1.100 port 22", "unreachable": true}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Well, it means you cannot connect to those hosts via ssh. You can confirm with `ansible all -a hostname  -m shell -u ubuntu --key-file=...`

Comment: Firewall (iptables, nft) outbound on localhost and/or inbound on remote host.  I think you will get a different error but there could also be restrictions in the authorized keys via `from=`[

Comment: @AllanWind ansible shell works
I get 10.0.1.50 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
ip-10-0-1-50 for every one, is ansible-playbook that gives the errors

Comment: @AllanWind it turns out that I need to add the file after the attributes

Comment: You mean options?

Comment: @AllanWind I meant options, yes

Comment: Also a heads-up, can set the default user and private key in .ansible.cfg https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We verified that `ansible all -a hostname  -m shell -u ubuntu --key-file=...` worked.  Options, we learned, have to specified before the playbook:

```
ansible-playbook --user ubuntu --private-key /path/to_key system_info.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it is important that the options are added before specifying the playbook `.yml` filename, otherwise they are ignored

```
ansible-playbook --user ubuntu --private-key /path/to_key system_info.yml
```